# How to display the embedded image of an email using html?

Tags: html, node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsoft graph api using nodejs to retrieve email.I am getting embedded image in the body of an email.If I pass the mail id to attachment api I am getting the embedded image content.But for display how to combine the embedded image in the body of the email.Please help me with displaying the message along with the embedded image(merging embedded message in the body of the email for display).Early response will be helpfull.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using for the presentation? Plain ole semantic HTML, a framework like React or Angular? How is the Node app interacting with UI?